# How to jQuery-ify elements returned by ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal-6

I ask this question in a Drupal context, but the answer may be generic and not specifically depend on Drupal.

I have some HTML elements that get updated/replaced via jQuery/ajax. On the first page load, the elements are properly processed by jQuery. However, the links included in the data returned after an ajax call are ignored by jQuery.

```
// This standard function ensures that elements are properly processed after first page load:   
Drupal.behaviors.events = function(context) {

   // This works as intended. Clicking on links works as intended: 
  $('.event_browse_location .parent_locations a:not(.events-processed)', context).addClass('events-processed')
    .bind('click', function() {
      $.get(Drupal.settings.basePath + '/events/location/' + parseInt(this.id, 10), null, browseLocation);
        return false;
  });
}                                   

var browseLocation = function(response) {
  var result = Drupal.parseJson(response);                                          
  // New elements are properly added to the DOM here:
  $('.event_browse_location').html(result.data);

   // However, this does not seem to have any effect.
   // The a elements in the new elements do not work as intended.
   // jQuery does not process them at all.
  $('.event_browse_location .parent_locations a:not(.events-processed)').addClass('events-processed')
    .bind('click', function() {
      $.get(Drupal.settings.basePath + '/events/location/' + parseInt(this.id, 10), null, browseLocation);
        return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: If possible, describe "links in the new elements do not work" ? At 1st glance, appear the `context` portion of `browseLocation` (2nd function) not defined ?

Comment: guest271314: I am suspecting you pointed at the right problem. I still need to figure how to solve it, but I think you put me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Removing the undefined second argument 'context' does not help, though :(

Comment: Is `Drupal.parseJson` a Drupal specific function ? Does `browseLocation` recursively call itself at last portion of `$.get()` ?

Comment: guest271314: sorry to have wasted your time. I tend to waste a lot of time on silly mistakes. see my answer. You may post as an answer, too and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there were two silly mistakes.

The first one was pointed out by guest271314: there was an undeclared variable in the original code I posted. I have amended the question accordingly.

Secondly, my jQuery selector was wrong and was excluding elements that were meant to be included. Fixing the selector fixed the problem.